# How to make Instagram Reels scrolling effect in react native Expo project with Scrollview, problem in calculating Dimensions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This is I have tried in App.js.
I have also printed dimensions and found that
screenHeight is not equals to windowHeight + statusBarHeight. Please explain to me why it is happening. Thanks in advance

```
import React from "react";

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("screen").height;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const statusBarHeight = StatusBar.currentHeight;

const Box = ({ color }) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.box, { backgroundColor: color, height: screenHeight }]}>
      <Text> screenHeight is {screenHeight}</Text>
      <Text> windowHeight is {windowHeight}</Text>
      <Text> statusBarHeight is {statusBarHeight}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function FeedInspireScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} pagingEnabled>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
      <Box color="red" />
      <Box color="green" />
      <Box color="red" />
      <Box color="green" />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
1;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: "pink",
  },
  box: {
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `vh` css unit? Like `100vh`

Comment: I dont know how to use vh in react native, may be its in react.